# How can I pass all the data of a Multiple View Type RecyclerView in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-recyclerview

in my Main Activity I have a RecyclerView. There are multiple types of Views that can be added. All with various types of data. One View Type carries & displays Customer Information, while another View Type displays a food item with additional text and a price.

After the User is done in main activity and moves onto another Activity I want to pass all the views and their data that are in the RecyclerView and re-create it in another Activity.

How can I encapsulate all the Views that have been entered into the RecyclerView so they can be passed back and forth between Activities? It also needs to be capable of handling different View Types with different Data.

**MainActivity.kt - Here is where the RecyclerView is born with multiple View types, I want to encapsulate it so it can be sent to different Activities and re-opened.**

```
package com.example.app

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.multiplerecyclerview.Adapter
import com.example.app.*
import com.example.app.Activites.*
import com.example.app.model.DataModel
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.main_activity.*

const val INDEX = 0

class OrderActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val list = ArrayList<DataModel>() /*ArrayList that is type Data Model. */
    val adapter = Adapter(this, getItemsList()) /* Adapter class is initialized and list is passed in the param. */

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this) /* Set the LayoutManager that this RecyclerView will use. */
        recyclerView.adapter = orderAdapter /* Adapter instance is set to the recyclerview to inflate the items. */

        /* Complete Button is clicked, now encapsulating RecyclerView and passing to next Activity. */
        complete_btn.setOnClickListener {
            val total = textViewPrice.text.toString()
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, LiveOrderActivity::class.java)  
            intent.putExtra("total", total) 
            intent.putExtra("customerName", customerName) 
            intent.putExtra("customerNumber", customerNumber) 
            intent.putExtra("customerPostal", customerPostal) 
            intent.putExtra("customerAddress", customerAddress) 

            /* HOW DO I PASS ALL THE DATA FROM THE RECYCLER VIEW HERE??? */


            startActivity(intent) 
        }

    }

    /* One ViewType, customer with a certain criteria of data. */
    private fun insertCustomer(customerName: String, customerNumber: String, customerPostal: String, customerAddress: String) {

        val newItem = DataModel(
            customerName = customerName,
            customerNumber = customerNumber,
            customerPostal = customerPostal,
            customerAddress = customerAddress,
            viewType = OrderAdapter.CUSTOMER
        ) /* Adding the item with correct arguments */
        list.add(INDEX, newItem) /* Adding Item at Position Index. */
        orderAdapter.notifyItemInserted(INDEX) /* Notifying the Adapter of the addition. */

    }

    /* Another ViewType, with a different set of data. */
    private fun insertCharge(charge: String) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Delivery Charge Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() /* Toast Message to confirm insertion. */

        val newItem = DataModel(
            delivery = "$charge",
            viewType = OrderAdapter.DELIVERY_CHARGE
        ) /* Adding the item with correct arguments */
        list.add(INDEX, newItem) /* Adding Item at Position Index. */
        orderAdapter.notifyItemInserted(INDEX) /* Notifying the Adapter of the addition. */
    }

    /* Another ViewType, with a different set of data. */
    private fun insertOpenFood(openFoodDetails: String, openFoodPrice: String) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Open Food Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() /* Toast Message to confirm insertion. */

        val newItem = DataModel(
            openFoodDetails = "$openFoodDetails",
            openFoodCharge = "$openFoodPrice",
            viewType = OrderAdapter.OPEN_FOOD_CHARGE
        ) /* Adding the item with correct arguments */
        list.add(INDEX, newItem) /* Adding Item at Position Index. */
        orderAdapter.notifyItemInserted(INDEX) /* Notifying the Adapter of the addition. */
    }

    private fun getItemsList(): ArrayList<DataModel> {

        //list.add(DataModel("Ham Burger","1","12.50", viewType = OrderAdapter.NO_TOPPING))
        //list.add(DataModel("American","1","12.50", viewType = OrderAdapter.NO_TOPPING))

        return list
    }
}
```

**Adapter.kt - This is the Adapter I am using for the RecyclerView in MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.multiplerecyclerview

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.app.model.DataModel
import com.example.app.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.openfood_charge.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.delivery_charge.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.customer_item.view.*

class Adapter(val context: Context, val items: ArrayList<DataModel>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    companion object {
        const val NO_TOPPING = 1
        const val DELIVERY_CHARGE = 9
        const val OPEN_FOOD_CHARGE = 12
        const val CUSTOMER = 21
    }

    /* Depending on the View Type, the correct one is passed. */
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        if(viewType == NO_TOPPING) 
            return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate( R.layout.food_item,parent,false))
        else if (viewType == DELIVERY_CHARGE) 
            return ViewHolder2(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.delivery_charge,parent,false))
        else if (viewType == OPEN_FOOD_CHARGE) 
            return ViewHolder3(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.openfood_charge,parent,false))
        else if (viewType == CUSTOMER) 
            return ViewHolder7(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.customer_item,parent,false))
        else 
            return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate( R.layout.food_item,parent,false))
        

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = items.get(position)

        if(holder is ViewHolder) {
            holder.productQuantity.text = item.itemQuantity
            holder.productName.text = item.itemName
            holder.productPrice.text = item.itemPrice
        }else if(holder is ViewHolder2) {
            holder.deliveryPrice.text = item.delivery
        } else if(holder is ViewHolder3) {
            holder.openFoodDetails.text = item.openFoodDetails
            holder.openFoodPrice.text = item.openFoodCharge
        } else if(holder is ViewHolder7) {
            holder.customer.text = item.customerName
            holder.number.text = item.customerNumber
            holder.eircode.text = item.customerPostal
            holder.address.text = item.customerAddress
        }

    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return items[position].viewType
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener {
        val productQuantity = view.productQuantityView
        val productName = view.productNameView
        val productPrice = view.productPriceView

        init { /* Acts like a constructor in Java. */
            view.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    }

    interface onItemClickListener {
        fun  onItemClick()
    }

    class ViewHolder2(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener {
        var deliveryPrice = view.deliveryPriceView
        val intent: Intent? = null
        init {
            view.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {

        }
    }

    class ViewHolder3(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var openFoodDetails = view.openFoodView
        var openFoodPrice = view.openFoodPriceView
    }

    class ViewHolder7(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val customer = view.nameView
        val number = view.mobileView
        val eircode = view.eircodeView
        val address = view.address1View

    }
}
```

**SecondActivity.kt - Here I want to recieve the RecyclerView's Data and recreate it.**

```
package com.example.app

class ActiveOrderActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val aorderList = generateList(50)
    private val adapter = AOrdersAdapter(aorderList)


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_active_order)

        recyclerview.adapter = adapter
        recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)

        insertItem()

        /* Here I want to recieve the RecyclerView Data! */
        val customerName: String = intent.getStringExtra("customerName").toString()
        val customerNumber: String = intent.getStringExtra("customerNumber").toString()
  

        if (customerName == "null") { /*If no RecyclerView has been passed. */

        } else {
            insertNewOrder(customerName, customerNumber, customerPostal, customerAddress, paymentType, paymentTotal)
        }

    }
    fun insertItem() {

    }

    private fun insertNewOrder(customerName: String, customerNumber: String, customerPostal: String, customerAddress: String, paymentType: String, paymentTotal: String) {

        val newItem = ActiveOrderModel(customerName,customerNumber, customerPostal, customerAddress, paymentTotal, paymentType)

        aorderList.add(0, newItem) /* Adding Item at Position Index. */
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(0) /* Notifying the Adapter of the addition. */

        /* Creating a new Customer.  */
        val order = hashMapOf(
            "customer Name" to customerName,
            "customer Number" to customerNumber,
            "eircode" to customerPostal,
            "address" to customerAddress,
            "paymentTotal" to paymentTotal
        )

    }

    private fun generateList(size: Int): ArrayList<ActiveOrderModel> {

        val list = ArrayList<ActiveOrderModel>()

        return list
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you don't have your activity implements a callback from your view holders? Then the activity will have the ability to receive data created by Recycler's Viewholders.

Comment: Hi Hau, Im quite new to RecyclerViews and I don't quite understand what you mean? If you could ellaborate please, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: You don't pull data OUT of the recycler view, you keep your data outside (in a repository for example, possibly using a ViewModel as well), and then use that repository of your "source of truth". When you need to mutate data (that is present in the RV), you mutate the data in the repository, save it (even if only in memory) and then update the RV to show the updated data. When you navigate to another activity, you simply ask the repository for the data again. Don't go *against* the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface

```
interface ViewHolderCallback{ fun onViewHolderSumitData(val data: Data) }
```

Then your ViewHolder, ViewHolder2, ViewHolder3, ViewHolder7 will require an implementation of this ViewHolderCallback interface via their constructor

```
class ViewHolder(view: View, val callback: ViewHolderCallback)
```

Your activity will implement ViewHolderCallback which requires it to override onViewHolderSumitData method. You will receive the Viewholder data here. Do whatever you want.

Then in your View Holders, when ever you feel need to sent data to activity execute callback.onViewHolderSumitData - you will need to create the Data param yourself base on the data inside your ViewHolder.

If the Data param in onViewHolderSumitData give you a hard time. Just create the method no param. Have activity implement it then set debug breakpoint. You will get the idea.

P/s you can foward the interface imlementation from Activty to View Holders vis Adapter

```
class Adapter(callback: ViewHolderCallback)
```